# QR Reader with VNDetectBarcodeRequest

Tags: ios, avfoundation, qr-code, apple-vision

I've setup an `AVCaptureSession` with a video data output and am attempting to use iOS 11's Vision framework to read QR codes. The camera is setup like basically any `AVCaptureSession` is. I will abbreviate and just show setting up the output.

```
let output = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
output.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: captureQueue)
captureSession.addOutput(output)

// I did this to get the CVPixelBuffer to be oriented in portrait.
// I don't know if it's needed and I'm not sure it matters anyway.
output.connection(with: .video)!.videoOrientation = .portrait
```

So the camera is up and running as always. Here is the code I am using to perform a `VNImageRequestHandler` for QR codes.

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    guard let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }
    let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, orientation: .up, options: [:])

    let qrRequest = VNDetectBarcodesRequest { request, error in
        let barcodeObservations = request.results as? [VNBarcodeObservation]
        guard let qrCode = barcodeObservations?.flatMap({ $0.barcodeDescriptor as? CIQRCodeDescriptor }).first else { return }
        if let code = String(data: qrCode.errorCorrectedPayload, encoding: .isoLatin1) {
            debugPrint(code)
        }
    }

    qrRequest.symbologies = [.QR]
    try! imageRequestHandler.perform([qrRequest])
}
```

I am using a QR code that encodes `http://www.google.com` as a test. The `debugPrint` line prints out:

> `AVGG\u{03}¢ò÷wwrævöövÆRæ6öÐì\u{11}ì`

I have tested this same QR code with the `AVCaptureMetadataOutput` that has been around for a while and that method decodes the QR code correctly. So my question is, what have I missed to get the output that I am getting?

(Obviously I could just use the `AVCaptureMetadataOutput` as a solution, because I can see that it works. But that doesn't help me learn how to use the Vision framework.)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is here:

```
if let code = String(data: qrCode.errorCorrectedPayload, encoding: .isoLatin1)
```

Try to use .utf8.

Also i would suggest to look at the raw output of the 'errorCorrectedPayload' without encoding. Maybe it already has correct encoding.

Comment: I went with `.isoLatin1` because that is the standard for QR codes ([reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBJG3_2.5.0/com.ibm.gen_studug.doc/c_grd_barcodes_qr_code.htm)). I will look into other encodings to see if helps. I'll also see if I can make any sense of the raw bytes. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: None of the other encodings I tried were any better. Some returned `nil` and some returned the same scrambled text.

Comment: After some testing, i think errorCorrectedPayload is not the QR data itself. In the source file of the CIQRCodeDescriptor it says that errorCorrectedPayload is - "The error-corrected codewords that comprise the QR code symbol." Which is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of errorCorrectedPayload says:
 -- QR Codes are formally specified in ISO/IEC 18004:2006(E). Section 6.4.10 "Bitstream to codeword conversion" specifies the set of 8-bit codewords in the symbol immediately prior to splitting the message into blocks and applying error correction. --

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine with `VNBarcodeObservation.payloadStringValue` instead of transforming `VNBarcodeObservation.barcodeDescriptor`.